# R CMD SHLIB 'undefined reference' and not generating .so/.dll for SWIG generated R wrapper

Tags: c++, c, r, dll, cmd

I am attempting to generate a .so/.dll from the CGP-Library found here:
http://www.cgplibrary.co.uk/files2/Download-txt.html

I have no interest in generating a package from this library, just to generate a .so/.dll that can be used in R to provide some extra functionlity.

I managed to create the R wrapper and .R files using SWIG-3.0.5 via:

```
swig -r cgp.i
```

with the .i file retrieved from the CGP-Library github repository here:
https://github.com/AndrewJamesTurner/CGP-Library

I managed to get RTools installed:

```
> find_rtools(T)
Scanning path...
ls : C:\Rtools\bin\ls.exe 
gcc: C:\Rtools\GCC-46~1.3\bin\gcc.exe 
VERSION.txt
Rtools version 3.1.0.1942 
Version: 3.1 
[1] TRUE
```

And set PATH to contain the appropriate directories:

```
C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;C:\R\R-3.0.2\bin\i386;%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;
C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;%SDS_ALGO_PATH%;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.4.3\;
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.4.3\Doctrine extensions for PHP\; 
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin; C:\swigwin-3.0.5\;
```

When I run:

```
R CMD SHLIB cgp_wrap.c
```

the command runs but only gives me the cgp_wrap.o file and no cgp_wrap.so/cgp_wrap.dll.

I get a string of what I guess are exceptions (which look like this):

```
cgp_wrap.o:cgp_wrap.c:(.text+0x561b): undefined reference to `_imp__repeatCGP'
cgp_wrap.o:cgp_wrap.c:(.text+0x58a9): undefined reference to `_imp__runCGP'
cgp_wrap.o:cgp_wrap.c:(.text+0x5b19): undefined reference to `_imp__copyChromoso
me'
```

There are too many to count and it looks as if every function in cgp_wrap.c may be returning an undefined reference.

I'm quite new to this (creating libraries and trying to interface to R) and it has taken me almost a week to get this far. But now I'm lost. I have no idea where to go from here.

The CGP-Library has been about for a few years now and I couldn't find anything that would suggest it is broken which leads me to the obvious conclusion that this is a PEBCAK issue.

If someone could find in their heart to take sympathy on me and lend a helping hand that would be awesome (and make you awesome too!)

Oh yeah, I'm running 32bit Windows 7 and R-3.0.2 (with Rstudio 0.98.1091).

Cheers

Edit: I have also tried running this on the assumption it is a c++ library (and not c) using the follwing in SWIGWIN:

```
swig -c++ -r -o example_wrap.cpp example.i
```

This made no difference other than giveing slightly different (yet essentially the same) messages in cmd.

Comment: Even if I run R CMD SHLIB on the original C library i still only get the .o file with no .dll/.so being generated.
I have slogged through several other methods including this here (http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/murdoch/software/compilingDLLs/existingDLL.html) and cannot for the life of me generate a functioning dll.
Has no one got any suggestions to get this up and running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was definitely PEBCAK. A very noobish one too. Turns out that not only do I have a long way to go before being halfway adept at this stuff but that the documentation is sometimes far from complete.

For those that wish to compile R compatible dlls from existing C source code and existing dlls give this a try (and sorry to those that are rolling thier eyes as they read this haha)

`swig -r example.i`

-this will generate your wrap_example.c and example.R files

`gcc -shared example_wrap.c example.c -I"full\path\to\R\include" -L"full\path\to\R.dll" -lR -lexample -o example.dll`

-this will generate a new dll from the SWIG R wrapped C library.

Things to look out for are making sure your include file and original C source code file have the same names and are in the SWIG directory. You can specify the full path to your existing dll or just put it in the SWIG directory too.

Huge thanks to Ian Bell for babysitting me through this.
You can find his GitHub repo here (https://github.com/ibell) which has a couple of working examples for SWIG/minGW and cross compiling from Linux to Windows via SWIG/minGW (all for R)